# Where is DotNetNuke page keywords stored in database?

Tags: t-sql, dotnetnuke, keyword, dotnetnuke-5

Which SQL Server table can I locate keywords associated with a page in DotNetNuke?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me awhile to find it...

Keywords information for a single page is stored in a "Keywords" field within a table called, somewhat unintuitively named, `Tabs`

Keywords are updated through a sproc named `AddTab`.

Found it through DotNetNuke source code.
[image]

Comment: Tabs is the old name for what are pages - unless you lived through version 2 and 3 it would seem unintuitive - good job finding it yourself